# CSS3: remove blur effect on scale

Tags: html, css, blur

I have a div. when I scale it, the text inside gets blurry. I want to remove the blur effect on scale.

```css
.content_text{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:thin black solid;
  transition:all 0.6s ease;
}

.content_text:hover{
 transform:scale(1.1);
 transition:all 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_text">
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: `I want to remove scale effect.` what you want to do actually?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another element to show animation. Please modify below code as per your requirements.

```css
.content_text{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.background{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:1;
  border:1px black solid;
  background:silver;
  transition:all 0.6s ease;
}
.content_text:hover .background{
 transform:scale(1.1);
 transition:all 0.6s ease;
}

.content_text .content{z-index:2;position:relative;}
```

```html
<div class="content_text">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There has no option to fixing text sharping during css animation. Its about how browser render text in scaling animation.

Answer (score -1):

Two options you have to reduce that `blur` on mouse hover:

**First -**
You can set transition to 0.15 like this:

```
transition:all 0.15s ease;
```

**Second -** 
You can increase `height`,`width` and `font-size` and reduce `transition` on mouse hover like this:

```css
.content_text{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:thin black solid;
  transition:all 0.15s ease;
}

.content_text:hover{ 
 transition:all 0.15s ease;
 width: 230px;
 height: 230px;
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_text">
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```